# How to Force UIButton to Refresh?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have working snippet along the lines of:

```
for (UIButton *b in buttonMapping) {
    [b setTitle:@"yo!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
}
```

There's four buttons, all four buttons update.  However, instead of updating one per second, four seconds go by & they all update.

How can I force UIButton to update?  Or is this not the recommend method for sleeping?

Comment: Remember to keep UI updates on the main thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[b setNeedsDisplay];`

I'd also not recommend sleeping the main thread (like you're doing here), since that disables all user interaction.

There are a couple of alternatives.  One might be to use an `NSTimer` to execute a particular method once a second.  However, the easier method would be to do something like:

```
for (NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [buttonMapping count]; idx++) {
  UIButton * b = [buttonMapping objectAtIndex:idx];
  [b performSelector:@selector(setNormalStateTitle:) withObject:@"yo!" afterDelay:(idx*60)];
}
```

Then add a method to UIButton (ie, a category) called `setNormalStateTitle:` that simply executes the `setTitle:forControlState:` method.  With this approach, you won't need the `setNeedsDisplay` method at all.

Comment: It doesn't look like UIButton responds to setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: apologies, it should just be `setNeedsDisplay`, not `setNeedsDisplay:YES`.  Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Changing to setNeedsDisplay compiles, however the behavior is the same.  Four seconds pass before any button is visibly changed.

Comment: @Bill then I'd go with the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` approach.  Because it really isn't a good idea to sleep your main thread.

Comment: That would work for this example, but really what I'm trying to do is show the user a sequence of buttons to press (a la the simple simon game of old).  So instead of setting title, what I really want to do is highlight the button for a few hundred milliseconds, de-highlight it, and then move on to the next button.  It's actually to cool to learn the performSelector method, but would make things a lot more complicated here.

Comment: @Bill that's still possible using the `setHighlighted:` selector.  Here's another option to consider: split off a second thread that has your loop and your `sleep()` calls, but instead of modifying the object directly, have it update the GUI on the main thread via `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`

Comment: @Dave How do I go from calling the class method (for the new thread) back to the instance methods (for updating the UI)?

Comment: Bill: Make the thread method an instance method. There are not many reasons to make a class method in Objective-C—the only solid one I can think of is the mixed-names-and-values syntax, and if you're doing a thread perform, you don't have the problem that that solves.