# How to enabled button after user select value from UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have created a new contact form I have 3 first name, Lastname, email country and create button, I enable the create button after firstname,Lastname and email when they are not empty. the county text field is populated after selecting from county PcikerView I test  !txtfCountry.text!.isEmpty on my editingChanged function but is not working.

```
self.txtfCountry.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)

 @IBOutlet var countryPicker : UIPickerView!

    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if !txtfFirstname.text!.isEmpty  && !txtfLastname.text!.isEmpty && !txtfEmail.text!.isEmpty  &&  !txtfCountry.text!.isEmpty{
            btnNext.isEnabled = true

            btnNext.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        }else{
            btnNext.isEnabled = false

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622036/how-to-force-uibutton-to-refresh)? In short, try calling `btnNext.setNeedsDisplay()` to tell iOS to redraw the button.